# Getting Skype to Post to a Group Conversation Via a Conversation ID

Tags: botframework

Hello Bot Framework engineers! I'll be honest here and mention straight off I'm not a developer, but I'm attempting to get my Skype Bot to work in Azure, and I've gotten most of the way there. The only thing I'd like to know at this point is how to get a ConversationID so I can send messages THROUGH the Skype bot to a group that the bot is a part of. Is that possible to get somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the skype conversation ID through the message. Using Ngrok, I found one which looked something like:

```
"conversation": {
    "isGroup": true,
    "id": "19:8cc9a9nnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnnn@thread.skype"
},
```

C# it would be something like:

```
turnContext.Activity.Conversation.Id
```